# Extracting entire std::string From a std::stringstream

Tags: c++

Please consider this code:

```
std::stringstream test;
test << std::string("This is a test.");
std::string str;
test >> str;
std::cout << "\"" << str << "\"" << std::endl;
```

This outputs only the string "This", rather than "This is a test."

Why is this so, and how can I get the entire string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::stringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str):

```
std::string str = test.str();
```

Comment: OK, should've seen that coming. I simplified my example too much. Please see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350927/member-function-template-to-covert-a-stdstring-to-any-numeric-type-or-to-a-std