# Member Function Template to Covert a std::string to Any Numeric Type or to a std::string

Tags: c++

Please consider the member function template. My question is embedded in comment form.

```
template<typename T>
GetValueResult GetValue(
                          const std::string &key,
                          T &val,
                          std::ios_base &(*manipulator)(std::ios_base &) = std::dec
                       )
{
   // This member function template is intended to work for all built-in
   // numeric types and std::string. However, when T = std::string, I get only
   // the first word of the map element's value. How can I fix this?

   // m_configMap is map<string, string>
   ConfigMapIter iter = m_configMap.find(key);

   if (iter == m_configMap.end())
      return CONFIG_MAP_KEY_NOT_FOUND;

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << iter->second;

   // Convert std::string to type T. T could be std::string.
   // No real converting is going on this case, but as stated above
   // I get only the first word. How can I fix this?
   if (ss >> manipulator >> val)
      return CONFIG_MAP_SUCCESS;
   else
      return CONFIG_MAP_VALUE_INVALID;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<<` and `>>` operators on streams are designed to work with tokens separated by whitespace. So if a string looks like "1 2" then your `stringstream` will only read in `1` on the first `<<`.

If you want multiple values I suggest you use a loop over the stream. Something like this might do...

```
//stringstream has a const string& constructor
std::stringstream ss(iter->second); 

while (ss >> manipulator >> value) { /* do checks here /* }
```

With that I would suggest you look at Boost and in particular [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) which might do what you want out of the box.

Comment: Won't this just read the *last* part of the string? I guess `value` is overwritten each time the statement is executed